# Wait 5 sec and view text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my code.. Now works you see element 5 sec and after 5 sec element is invisible. How I can correct code and first 5 sec is invisible and after 5 sec is visible.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('app').className = 'paa';
}, 5000);
```

```css
p.paa {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<p id="app">Test!</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to give it a class which hides the element. When the timer has reached five seconds, remove said class to make it visible.

`opacity` is a CSS3 property and will not work in all browsers. `display` will work for all, but you can tweak this logic to work for `opacity` is you wish.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('app');
  
  removeClass(el, 'hidden');
}, 5000);

function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) {
    el.classList.remove(className);
  } else {
    el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' +
        className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
  }
}
```

```css
p.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="app" class="hidden">Test!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML you can have the `paa` class at beginning

```
<p id="app" class="paa">Test!</p>
```

and then you can remove the class after 5 seconds

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('app').className.replace("paa", "");
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse it! if you don't understand your code, you must to have problems in future.

```
 <p id="app">show and hide</p>
```

CSS

```
 #app { opacity: 0; }
 .paa { opacity: 1; }
```

JS

```
 setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('app').className = 'paa';
 }, 5000);
```